# Can Newtonsoft Json.NET skip serializing empty lists?

Tags: c#, list, serialization, json.net

I am trying to serialize some legacy objects that "lazy creates" various lists. I can not change the legacy behavior.

I have boiled it down to this simple example:

```
public class Junk
{
    protected int _id;

    [JsonProperty( PropertyName = "Identity" )]
    public int ID 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }

        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }

    protected List<int> _numbers;
    public List<int> Numbers
    {
        get
        {
            if( null == _numbers )
            {
                _numbers = new List<int>( );
            }

            return _numbers;
        }

        set
        {
            _numbers = value;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        Junk j = new Junk( ) { ID = 123 };

        string newtonSoftJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( j, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented );

        Console.WriteLine( newtonSoftJson );

    }
}
```

The current results are:
{
  "Identity": 123,
  "Numbers": []
}

I would like to get:
{
  "Identity": 123
}

That is, I would like to skip any lists, collections, arrays, or such things that are empty.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

In case you didn't find a solution to this, [the answer](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConditionalProperties.htm) is remarkably simple when you manage to track it down.

If you are permitted to extend the original class then add a `ShouldSerializePropertyName` function to it.  This should return a Boolean indicating whether or not that property should be serialized for the current instance of the class.  In your example this might look like this (not tested but you should get the picture):

```
public bool ShouldSerializeNumbers()
{
    return _numbers.Count > 0;
}
```

This approach works for me (albeit in VB.NET).  If you're not allowed to modify the original class then the `IContractResolver` approach described on the the linked page is the way to go.

Comment: can I do in a generic way? I do not know all the property names but want all empty arrays to be null.

Comment: This works for generic lists also!

public List<EmailAttachment> attachments { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Prevent empty attachments JSON - otherwise SendGrid will reject
        /// </summary>
        public bool ShouldSerializeattachments()
        {
            // https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm
            // Don't serialize the attachments array if it doesn't have any items
            return attachments.Count > 0;
        }

Answer (score 29):

Regarding David Jones' suggestion to use `IContractResolver`, this works for me to cover all `IEnumerables` variations without explicitly modifying the class that needs to be serialized:

```
public class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public static readonly ShouldSerializeContractResolver Instance = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver();

        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization) {
            JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

            if (property.PropertyType != typeof(string)) {
                if (property.PropertyType.GetInterface(nameof(IEnumerable)) != null)
                    property.ShouldSerialize =
                        instance => (instance?.GetType().GetProperty(property.PropertyName).GetValue(instance) as IEnumerable<object>)?.Count() > 0;
            }
            return property;
        }
}
```

Then I build it into my settings object:

```
static JsonSerializerSettings JsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
    ContractResolver = ShouldSerializeContractResolver.Instance,
};
```

and use it like this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject, JsonSettings);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found I had to replace the two `if`s with a single one to get it to work though: `if (property.PropertyType.GetInterface(nameof(IEnumerable)) != null)`

Comment: @TomRobinson - Thank you, that's helpful to know! My memory of the nuts and bolts of .NET is rusty hehe

Comment: I had to change the line  
`instance => (instance?.GetType().GetProperty(property.PropertyName).GetValue(instance) as IEnumerable<object>)?.Count() > 0;`  
to   
`instance => (instance?.GetType().GetProperty(property.PropertyName)?.GetValue(instance) as IEnumerable)?.OfType<object>().Count() > 0;`
otherwise objects in not empty IEnumerables would be serialized as "{}"

Comment: I think we should also `return base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);` instead of just `return property` on the last line. And `return property` only if we find an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: You should use `GetProperty(property.UnderlyingName)` instead of `GetProperty(property.PropertyName)`, in case you're using a naming strategy.

Answer (score 10):

Bryan you are most the way there you don't need the overhead of the instance variable and you need to trap both field & member instances plus I would not run the count operation which requires the enumerable to exhaust the entire collection you can simply run the MoveNext() function.

```
public class IgnoreEmptyEnumerableResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member,
        MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (property.PropertyType != typeof(string) &&
            typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = instance =>
            {
                IEnumerable enumerable = null;
                // this value could be in a public field or public property
                switch (member.MemberType)
                {
                    case MemberTypes.Property:
                        enumerable = instance
                            .GetType()
                            .GetProperty(member.Name)
                            ?.GetValue(instance, null) as IEnumerable;
                        break;
                    case MemberTypes.Field:
                        enumerable = instance
                            .GetType()
                            .GetField(member.Name)
                            .GetValue(instance) as IEnumerable;
                        break;
                }

                return enumerable == null ||
                       enumerable.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
                // if the list is null, we defer the decision to NullValueHandling
            };
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

Comment: All my data schemas had no fields defined so I didn't run into this case. Thanks! Do you need the null-conditional on *MemberTypes.Property* but not on *MemberTypes.Field* for some specific reason? Also, I didn't think that *string* objects would get included in my check, but the logic should still apply, right? Or is it better to defer handling of them to Json.Net?

Answer (score 3):

Just to be pendantic commonorgarden, I structured the if test to be:

```
public bool ShouldSerializecommunicationmethods()
{
    if (communicationmethods != null && communicationmethods.communicationmethod != null && communicationmethods.communicationmethod.Count > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

As an empty list will often be null too. Thanks for posting the solution. ATB.

Comment: Another option you have is to make use of the "NullValueHandling" attribute:  [JsonProperty("yourPropertyName", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)].  That should help reduce the need for the null checks which will refine your if checks a bit.  Just thought I'd mention it as you may find it handy.

Comment: In the ShouldSerialize method you still need to check for nulls, otherwise a call to ShouldSerialize will throw an exception on nulls. Even if the serializer is coded to ignore exceptions when checking the ShouldSerialize methods the exception being raised at all will add an unnecessary overhead that could affect performance. So you potentially gain a lot more than you lose by checking for null first.