# NullValueHandling for properties that are not null but have no data in them

Tags: c#, json, json.net, poco

In my POCO object, I have some sub objects that may or may not have some data in them. However, they're declared during object initialization so they're not null.

When I convert them to JSON objects, they show up even if I set the NullValueHandling to Ignore because they're not null.

What's the best way to deal with them so that they don't show up when I serialize my POCO objects to JSON?

Here's an example of a POCO object:

```
public class Person
{
   [JsonProperty("id")]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("firstName")]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("lastName")]
   public string LastName { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("addresses", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
   public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; } = new List<Address>();
}
```

In this example, even if I don't have any addresses for this person, when serialized the person class, I see `addresses: []` as an empty array.

I really would like to be able to ignore all properties with no data in them. What's the best approach to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answers seems to be pretty simple : 
[Can Newtonsoft Json.NET skip serializing empty lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320968/can-newtonsoft-json-net-skip-serializing-empty-lists)

> If you are permitted to extend the original class then add a
>   ShouldSerializePropertyName function to it. This should return a
>   Boolean indicating whether or not that property should be serialized
>   for the current instance of the class. In your example this might look
>   like this (not tested but you should get the picture):

Comment: I love it when the solution is that simple :-)