# C# Delete Text In JSON file

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to create a json file from c#. I need to remove this array, "judgmentLinkedAccount": [], if it's empty. I tried:

```
    public static void ReplaceText() 
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(FileToExport.exportFile);
        string textToReplace = "\"" + "judgmentLinkedAccount" + "\"" + ": []";
        text = text.Replace(textToReplace, "");
        File.WriteAllText(FileToExport.exportFile, text);
    }
```

But it doesn't remove the text. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1) Can you share a [mcve] showing the input JSON?  2) Are you creating the JSON?  If so, why not simply skip serializing the `judgmentLinkedAccount` member?  E.g., if you are using [tag:json.net] to generate your JSON, see [Can Newtonsoft Json.NET skip serializing empty lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11320968/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

change the content of textToReplace with textToReplace  = "\"judgmentLinkedAccount\": []";